# Flutter: How to make a nav bar like in youtube app?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

I am trying to implement navbar like this. But with standart flutter navbar I got a problem with central item - because there is some space for text and it is not centered properly. And also beacause of size it looks more thick

[image]

This is widget for bottom nav bar i use

```
 return BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).bottomAppBarColor,
          selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey[600],
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          selectedFontSize: 11,
          unselectedFontSize: 10,
          items: widget.children
              .map(
                (entry) => BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: entry.icon,
                  activeIcon: entry.activeIcon,
                  label: entry.label ?? '',
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
          currentIndex: widget.tabsRouter.activeIndex,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
        );
```

And then like that

```
AutoTabsScaffold(
          routes: [
            CalendarRouter(),
            EmployeesRouter(),
            EmployeesRouter(),
            EmployeesRouter(),
            EmployeesRouter()
          ],
          bottomNavigationBuilder: (_, tabsRouter) => BottomNavBarWidget(
            tabsRouter: tabsRouter,
            children: [
              BottomBarItem(
                label: 'Schedule',
                child: CalendarScreen(),
                activeIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.home_sharp,
                  size: 24,
                ),
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.home_outlined,
                  size: 24,
                ),
              ),
             BottomBarItem(
                activeIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.add_circle_outline,
                  size: 32,
                ),
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.add_circle_outline,
                  size: 32,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh added code. check out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this your pubspc.yml file :

```
dependencies:
  persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^4.0.2
```

then Example : Your Desire one is the style 17 no .

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar/persistent-tab-view.dart';

import 'custom-widget-tabs.widget.dart';
import 'modal-screen.dart';
import 'screens.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

BuildContext testContext;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Persistent Bottom Navigation Bar example project',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MainMenu(),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
        '/first': (context) => MainScreen2(),
        // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
        '/second': (context) => MainScreen3(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MainMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  MainMenu({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainMenuState createState() => _MainMenuState();
}

class _MainMenuState extends State<MainMenu> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Sample Project"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("Custom widget example"),
              onPressed: () => pushNewScreen(
                context,
                screen: CustomWidgetExample(
                  menuScreenContext: context,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("Built-in styles example"),
              onPressed: () => pushNewScreen(
                context,
                screen: ProvidedStylesExample(
                  menuScreenContext: context,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

// ----------------------------------------- Provided Style ----------------------------------------- //

class ProvidedStylesExample extends StatefulWidget {
  final BuildContext menuScreenContext;
  ProvidedStylesExample({Key key, this.menuScreenContext}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProvidedStylesExampleState createState() => _ProvidedStylesExampleState();
}

class _ProvidedStylesExampleState extends State<ProvidedStylesExample> {
  PersistentTabController _controller;
  bool _hideNavBar;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);
    _hideNavBar = false;
  }

  List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
    return [
      MainScreen(
        menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext,
        hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
        onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
          });
        },
      ),
      MainScreen(
        menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext,
        hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
        onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
          });
        },
      ),
      MainScreen(
        menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext,
        hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
        onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
          });
        },
      ),
      MainScreen(
        menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext,
        hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
        onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
          });
        },
      ),
      MainScreen(
        menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext,
        hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
        onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
          });
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
    return [
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        title: "Home",
        activeColorPrimary: Colors.blue,
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
        inactiveColorSecondary: Colors.purple,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.search),
        title: ("Search"),
        activeColorPrimary: Colors.teal,
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
        routeAndNavigatorSettings: RouteAndNavigatorSettings(
          initialRoute: '/',
          routes: {
            '/first': (context) => MainScreen2(),
            '/second': (context) => MainScreen3(),
          },
        ),
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
          title: ("Add"),
          activeColorPrimary: Colors.blueAccent,
          activeColorSecondary: Colors.white,
          inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.white,
          routeAndNavigatorSettings: RouteAndNavigatorSettings(
            initialRoute: '/',
            routes: {
              '/first': (context) => MainScreen2(),
              '/second': (context) => MainScreen3(),
            },
          ),
          onPressed: (context) {
            pushDynamicScreen(context,
                screen: SampleModalScreen(), withNavBar: true);
          }),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.message),
        title: ("Messages"),
        activeColorPrimary: Colors.deepOrange,
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
        routeAndNavigatorSettings: RouteAndNavigatorSettings(
          initialRoute: '/',
          routes: {
            '/first': (context) => MainScreen2(),
            '/second': (context) => MainScreen3(),
          },
        ),
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
        title: ("Settings"),
        activeColorPrimary: Colors.indigo,
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
        routeAndNavigatorSettings: RouteAndNavigatorSettings(
          initialRoute: '/',
          routes: {
            '/first': (context) => MainScreen2(),
            '/second': (context) => MainScreen3(),
          },
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Navigation Bar Demo')),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text('This is the Drawer'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: PersistentTabView(
        context,
        controller: _controller,
        screens: _buildScreens(),
        items: _navBarsItems(),
        confineInSafeArea: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        stateManagement: true,
        navBarHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom > 0
            ? 0.0
            : kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
        hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
        bottomScreenMargin: 0.0,
        onWillPop: (context) async {
          await showDialog(
            context: context,
            useSafeArea: true,
            builder: (context) => Container(
              height: 50.0,
              width: 50.0,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                child: Text("Close"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
          return false;
        },
        selectedTabScreenContext: (context) {
          testContext = context;
        },
        hideNavigationBar: _hideNavBar,
        decoration: NavBarDecoration(
            colorBehindNavBar: Colors.indigo,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
        popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
        itemAnimationProperties: ItemAnimationProperties(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
          curve: Curves.ease,
        ),
        screenTransitionAnimation: ScreenTransitionAnimation(
          animateTabTransition: true,
          curve: Curves.ease,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        ),
        navBarStyle:
            NavBarStyle.style17, // Choose the nav bar style with this property
      ),
    );
  }
}



// ----------------------------------------- Custom Style ----------------------------------------- //

class CustomNavBarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int selectedIndex;
  final List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> items;
  final ValueChanged<int> onItemSelected;

  CustomNavBarWidget({
    Key key,
    this.selectedIndex,
    @required this.items,
    this.onItemSelected,
  });

  Widget _buildItem(PersistentBottomNavBarItem item, bool isSelected) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: IconTheme(
              data: IconThemeData(
                  size: 26.0,
                  color: isSelected
                      ? (item.activeColorSecondary == null
                          ? item.activeColorPrimary
                          : item.activeColorSecondary)
                      : item.inactiveColorPrimary == null
                          ? item.activeColorPrimary
                          : item.inactiveColorPrimary),
              child: isSelected ? item.icon : item.inactiveIcon ?? item.icon,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
            child: Material(
              type: MaterialType.transparency,
              child: FittedBox(
                  child: Text(
                item.title,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: isSelected
                        ? (item.activeColorSecondary == null
                            ? item.activeColorPrimary
                            : item.activeColorSecondary)
                        : item.inactiveColorPrimary,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    fontSize: 12.0),
              )),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: items.map((item) {
            int index = items.indexOf(item);
            return Flexible(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  this.onItemSelected(index);
                },
                child: _buildItem(item, selectedIndex == index),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

For More : Check the [Link](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar/example)

Comment: Style n17 fits with my problem, but thanks a lot