# Create youtube like bottom navigation bar in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement bottom nav bar just like in youtube app, with the centre add icon being expanded. Here is the image below.
[image]

Here [Flutter: How to make a nav bar like in youtube app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70488378/flutter-how-to-make-a-nav-bar-like-in-youtube-app) the answer is to use package, but is there any way to implement this without using a package?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BottomNavigationBar` .That is existing class in flutter
For Reference You can check on this flutter documentation site ,
**https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html**

Answer (score 0):

In the `Scaffold` widget, there is a property called `bottomNavigationBar`, which can take any widget you want to put in there and place it at the bottom of the screen.

Typically a lot of the time you could place the `BottomAppBar` widget in there. Or alternatively if you really want to you can create your own app bar widget completely.

See this for `BottomAppBar`
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomAppBar-class.html